# MoEngage SDK Application Crash - Failed resolution of ProcessLifecycleOwner

Tags: android, moengage

On integrating the MoEngage SDK, facing a crash on application launch with the below stacktrace.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/lifecycle/ProcessLifecycleOwner;
          at com.moe.pushlibrary.MoEHelper.r(:1005)
          at com.moengage.core.MoEngage.a(:210)
```

Integrated Versions: Catalog version - 3.2.0

Modules integrated: core, inapp, pushAmp, pushAmpPlus, richNotification

How can this be resolved?

Followed the steps mentioned in the guide here - https://developers.moengage.com/hc/en-us/articles/360062022652#h_01H8ZMW3Z14442JF885KN2SV0E

Comment: As this seems like an inner issue with moengage, it would help if you share the integration steps and show the relevant files.